# Dataproc: Can user create workers of different instance types?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, dataproc

scenario:
master: x1 machine type
workers: x2-machine type, x3-machine type.

For the above scenario: AWS EMR instance fleet allows users to create different worker instance types. From dataproc console, I noticed options is for only, N-worker types(all worker types of same type). Does Dataproc HDI also support this option of creating different instance types for worker?

Answer (score 1):

Dataproc supports 2 types of worker group: (primary) workers and [secondary workers](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/compute/secondary-vms). But they must have the same machine type as of Q2 2022, there is only one flag `--worker-machine-type` for it.

Note that it does allow secondary workers to have different disk type, disk size, accelerator, etc. See this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/clusters/create) for more details.